# Sull'uso della preposizione "presso"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Nel libro *Verde acqua* di Marisa Madieri ho letto:

> "Poco tempo dopo l'inizio dell'anno scolastico gli zii andarono ad abitare proprio di fronte all'Istituto Campostrini, in un bell'appartamento nuovo situato in un complesso di case costruite da una cooperativa della Sidarma, società *presso* la quale lo zio era stato assunto come impiegato."

Questa preposizione,  "presso", mi è sempre sembrata molto curiosa perché non esiste una preposizione simile nella mia lingua. Per questa ragione, non capisco bene quali siano gli usi di tale preposizione. Potreste spiegarmeli?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si usa soprattutto per indicare che qualcosa si trova vicino a un'altra, o nei suoi dintorni, o nella zona circostante (cfr. "cerca de", "a prop de", "al voltant de", "en los alrededores de" e similari):

> Un paese presso Milano
>
> Il museo si trova presso la stazione.

In quest'uso si può sostituire quasi sempre con "vicino a", "nei dintorni di", "nelle vicinanze di". C'è anche un'espressione idiomatica (**"nei pressi di"**) con lo stesso significato:

> Ha un orto nei pressi del lago.

Però, come forse già immagini, l'uso da te citato è un po' differente (meraviglie dell'italiano).
In combinazione con certi verbi (mi vengono in mente "lavorare" e "abitare") il significato cambia leggermente:

> Mario abita ancora presso i suoi genitori

significa: abita ancora coi suoi genitori, abita ancora dai suoi, abita ancora a casa dei suoi (anche: abita presso di loro).

> Mario lavora presso la nostra azienda

significa: lavora qui da noi, lavora nella nostra azienda (anche: lavora presso di noi).

Si usa anche in un certo tipo di linguaggio commerciale:

> Presso di noi troverete [le ultime novità | le migliori marche] etc.

In questo caso l'espressione più comune e colloquiale è

> Da noi troverete ...

Un altro uso idiomatico è in riferimento alle pubblicazioni editoriali:

> L'autore ha pubblicato il suo nuovo libro presso Bompiani.

In questo secondo uso, "presso" non si può sostituire con "nei pressi di" o con "vicino a"; se si fa, il significato cambia:

> Vive presso una comunità (== vive in una comunità)

vs

> Vive nei pressi di una comunità (== la sua abitazione si trova nelle vicinanze di una comunità)

Oppure:

> Presso di noi troverete ... (== nel nostro negozio troverete ...)

vs

> Vicino a noi troverete ... (== da qualche parte qui nelle vicinanze, però non da noi)

Comment: Cercando informazione su Marisa Madieri ho letto anche queste frasi con la preposizione *presso*: «Ha pubblicato ***presso*** Einaudi *Verde Acqua* (1987) e *La Radura* (1992). *La Conchiglia e altri racconti* sono usciti nel 1998 ***presso*** Scheiwiller.»

Comment: Sì, effettivamente "presso" si usa idiomaticamente nella forma che hai trovato anche con riferimento alle pubblicazioni con una casa editrice.

Comment: Potresti aggiungerlo alla risposta?

Comment: Ora l'ho aggiunto.